# How to generate jbpmn using java api

Tags: spring, jbpm

My task is need to generate jbpmn dynamically , Can someone help me to  generate jbpmn using jbpm with Java and spring , drools

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [jbpm fluent API](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.41.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_process_fluent_api) which allows you to create a process using Java API.